# Limit of A Definite Integral $I := \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^\pi \cos(R\cos\theta)\sinh(R\sin\theta)d\theta$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Excuse me.

I had tried to solve the limit of definite integral, that is
\begin{equation}
I := \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^\pi \cos(R\cos\theta)\sinh(R\sin\theta)d\theta
\end{equation}
to prove that
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi
\end{equation}
using Cauchy's integral.

I hope the integral $I$ has result $\pi$.  How can it?  I had tried to consult Wolfram Alpha, but I failed.

Thank you very much before.

Comment: I think it is possible to find the $I$ by the second integral. But, finding the second integral from the first limit is not a very efficient way.